# How to setup Android, iOS and Visual Studio with Xamarin Studio?

Tags: c#, ios, visual-studio-2012, xamarin-studio

I'm new to stack overflow as well as new to Xamarin Studio. I recently downloaded and installed XamarinInstaller which installed Andriod SDK, JAVA SDK, Xamarin Studio and Xamarin for Visual Studio [At that time of installation Visual Studio was not installed] on my system and after that it asked me to install NET Framework 4.5.1 and GTK# for .NET which I did. After all this i installed Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate and when i opened and checked Xamarin Studio i couldn't code for Android it gives me some error and also on Visual Studio whenever i try to start a new project i can't find andriod or ios on it.

How to setup Android and ios on Xamarin Studio?
How to link Xamarin on Visual Studio?
How to setup Android and iOS on Visual Studio?

Comment: Post the error message that you got.

Comment: I downloaded that example andriod app Tasky and i tried to debug it and it gives me this error [link](http://imgur.com/x7CooVk)

Comment: Refer this page http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/26395/fixed-could-not-find-android-jar-for-api-level-21

Comment: Also it doesn't show andriod in visual studio on the left side where we select the languages we want to code in [here](http://imgur.com/IS5Q9zf)

Comment: You would probably have to uninstall Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android from Programs and then rerun the installer to get them install again so as to register on Visual Studio.

Comment: Thanks, I've reinstalled it again and it works on Visual Studio.